# Making sprite rotate smoothly

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a sprite that I want to rotate smoothly and face the opposite direction:

This is my render function:

```
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    spriteBatch.begin();        

    if(bug.getX() >= (int)(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 100) && bug.getY() >= (int)(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 100)){
        bug.rotate(rotDeg);
        turn = !turn;
    }
    else if(bug.getX() <= 0 && bug.getY() <= 0){
        bug.rotate(rotDeg);
        turn = !turn;
    }

    if(!turn){          
        bug.translate(v.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), v.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    }
    else{
        bug.translate(-(v.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()), -(v.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()));
    }


    bug.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

What my code does is that when it reaches the destination (top right corner, or bottom left corner), it immediatly turns facing the opposite direction. How would I make this turn smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "smoothly" would mean for you that the turning direction does not flip directly when reaching the border, but instead, it should stop directly and accelerates over a little time.

Therefore use three float values instead of `rotDeg`: `currentRotation`, `rotationStep` and `maxRotation`. With them you can model a smooth acceleration:

You call `bug.rotate(currentRotation)` in every render call. When reaching the border, set `currentRotation = 0`. Now everytime you call `bug.rotate()` increase `currentRotation` by `rotationStep` as long as `currentRotation < maxRotation`. You have to search for appropriate values for them depending on your application speed.

In case you want to let your bug fade out the screen a little, meaning not stopping the rotation immediately, use a further flag, that indicates whether the rotation speed is increasing or decreasing in the case `|currentRotation| < maxRotation`. Depending on this flag either increment or decrement `currentrotation` by `rotationStep`. This would make the border feel like rubber for the user, where the sprite fades in, stops and smoothly accelerates out.